# Integrate Facebook Like button in website... With comments option

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, fbml

Please see:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

I successfully integrated a [Like] button in my website using this link.

On the developers website, when I click the [Like] button, a popup appears telling this:

```
You like this.
Share it on Facebook with a comment...
[                         ]
           [Post to Facebook] [Cancel]
```

On my website, there is no such popup.
I tested both iframe and FBML versions.

Does anyone has a solution, or is this feature only reserved for www.facebook.com ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing myself as I'm unable to get it working.
I haven't seen this popup anywhere on the web outside of Facebook's documentation.

Comment: Me too, I hadn't seen this elsewhere neither...
Until now: http://blog.bottomlessinc.com/2010/04/administer-your-ghost-pages-shared-by-the-new-facebook-like-button/
This page shows the comment box.
And as a bonus, it shows how to administer the ghost page created by such Like button.  

Thanks very much for your answers.
I haven't had the time to test them yet.
I will reply and note answers next week when I will be able to test.

Comment: that page seems to use a wordpress plugin to add the comment box.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) says:
"When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?
If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, user's will always have the option to add an optional comment to the like. If you are using the Iframe version, users will have the option to add a comment only if you are using the 'standard' layout with a width of at least 450 px. If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence."

You could also replace the like button with a [share](http://www.facebook.com/share/) button and be able to add comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have all of the required meta data in the meta tags.  See here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.
By default, if these meta-tags are not present, it takes the page standard meta-tags (title, description...).

Answer (score 0):

See this thread on the Facebook developer forum : http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=57294

It might help you even though I still didn't get it to work.

**EDIT:**

Check out this other thread : http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=57402

The last comment concludes that the page must not be on localhost for it to actually work.